# How can I access I web app that I am running locally in AWS from my computer?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

I got AWS today and have managed to get a web app up and running there, as you can see here:
[image]

I have managed to do that by following this guide:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-flask.html#python-flask-run-locally

But I have not succeeded in accessing that web app from my browser. In the browser on my physical computer I try to visit the address http://127.0.0.1:5000/ and I get ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED:
[image]

What is the likely reason for this?
How can I resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that your website is running on the "EC2" instance and 127.0.0.1 is relative the EC2 instance not your laptop.

SO in order to access your website you need to get public ip address of the host. Then enter it instead of 127.0.0.1 and assuming you opend up security group then you should see the result.